# C++ Module "failed to read module 'std.io.gcm': No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying to test c++ module using the [docker image](https://gitlab.kitware.com/ben.boeckel/cxx-modules-sandbox/tree/docker)

```
docker pull benboeckel/cxx-modules-sandbox:latest
docker run -it image_id


sh-4.4$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 9.0.1 20190301 (experimental) [c++-modules:20190305-1618]
```

Then, create a test file.

```
import std.io;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following error :

> sh-4.4$ g++ -o m main.cpp -std=c++2a  -fmodules-ts  In module imported
>   at main.cpp:1:1: std.io: error: failed to read module 'std.io.gcm': No
>   such file or directory std.io: fatal error: jumping off the crazy
>   train to crashville compilation terminated.

**update:**

The following code works fine.

```
//m.cpp
export module M;
export int sq(int i) { return i*i; }

//main.cpp
import M;
int main() { return sq(9); }

g++  -o m main.cpp m.cpp -std=c++2a -fmodules-ts
```

Comment: What is `std.io`? Is that part of GCC's modules implementation?

Comment: @NicolBolas I copy the code from c++ module ts: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4720.pdf

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Does GCC provide a `std.io` module? If not, then you can't import it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks, hope I can find it in its documents

Comment: @NicolBolas I think in this docker image, the std.io is not ready. But the compiler do support module :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Modules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1103r2.pdf) got added to the C++20 draft, but it doesn't imply that the standard library is now modularized. [There's an effort to modularize it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1453r0.html), but we don't have anything concrete so far:

> While we appear to have achieved consensus on a design for the modules language feature, our plan for how and when the C++ standard library will be modularized are not as mature. Some proposals have been made ([[P0581R1]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1453r0.html#biblio-p0581r1) and [[P1212R0]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1453r0.html#biblio-p1212r0)) and preliminary discussions have taken place ([[2018-Jacksonville-LEWG-P0581R0-Minutes]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1453r0.html#biblio-2018-jacksonville-lewg-p0581r0-minutes) and [[2018-San-Diego-EWG-P1212R0-Minutes]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1453r0.html#biblio-2018-san-diego-ewg-p1212r0-minutes)), but we haven’t committed to a path yet. Given that the C++20 cycle is nearly over, it’s time for us to make a decision on our strategy for standard library modules in C++20.

Comment: Thanks! I will looking forward to using it. It is a really nice feature.